# Extract Date from user typed data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

Given a NVARCHAR column with the data below, how can a SQL Query be written to extract the closest date from each row?  The final format needs to be MM/DD/YYYY.  Any extra data should be dropped off.  Anything that cannot be converted should result in a NULL value. Is there any pattern matching options available that may work?

Values like ' **6/2015 :**    ' mean 06/01/2015
Values like ' **/2014 :  3-10%** ' mean 01/01/2014
Values like ' **Dec/2014 :** ' mean 12/01/2014

```
 3/2015 :  >10%  
 Dec/2014 : 
 11/2014 :    
 4/2015 :  
3-10% B
 6/2015 :    
 6/2015: >10% 
 1/2015:  
 /2014 :  Patient
 /2015 :  3-10% 
 3/2015 :  
 1/2015 :  >10%  
 /2014 :  >10%  
 6/2015 :  >10%  
12/2014 but 
    7/2015 :  3-10% 
 12/2014: >10% 
 6/2015 :  3-10% 
    5/2015 :    
 /2015 :  
 11/2013 :  
9/2012Acti
 6/2015:  
 6/2014 :    
 1/2015 :    
 /2014 :  3-10% 
  Jan/2015 :    
ed 7/2012: --will order
 9/30/2014 :  <5 %  
 9/2015 :  >10%  
 1/19/2015 :    
  6/2/2015 :  >10%  
11/27/2014 :    
 /2014 :    
 3/2015 :  Patient
 4/22/2014 :  >10%  
 4/2015 :    
 7/12/2015 :    
 6/2014 :    
ystemic :  
 4/2015 :    
 5/2015 :  3-10% 
   11/2014 :    
 1/2015 :    
 6/2015 :    
 10/2014 :    
rit    :  3-10% 
 4/2015 :    
 5/2014 :    
 7/31/2014 :    
   2014 :  >10%  
 7/2015 :  >10%  
 6/2015 :  3-10% 
ugust /2014: 3-10%  
 1/2015 :  3-10% 
10/23/2015 :  >10%  
 8/14/2015 :  >10%  
d 7/2015 :  Examinati
lear today  2/2014: 
rthrit :  
 /2014 :  Patient
    4/2015 :  3-10%nv
 6/2015 :  >10%  
 8/2014 :  >10%  
  2014 :    
 4/2015 :    
   12/2014 :  >10%  
8/15/2014A
 8/2014 :    
 4/2015 :  Today )% 
c arthritn 2014, 3-
 8/2014:  
 6/15/2015 :    
  2/4/2015 :  
Anvolved  
 /2014 :  >10%  
 4/2014: 10-15% 
 10/2014:  
thrit  :  >10%  
d 2/2015 :  Unremarka
    3/2013 :  
   10/2015 :  >10%  
PPD there) :    
  2/17/2014 : 
    8/2015 :    
 /2014 :    
 8/17/2015 :  
t /2014:  
 4/2014 :    
 1  5/2015 :    
 4/2015 :  
April 2015 :    
 3/2014 :  3-10% 
 8/2015 :  3-10% 
2/2012Acti
 12/2014 :  >10%  
 4/2015 :    
 /2014 :  3-10% 
 11/2014 :    
d 4/2015 :  
 1/19/2015 :    
 11/2014 :  >10%  
vered:   :  Examinati
    7/2015 :    
  Oct/2014 :    
 8/2015 :    
 2  3/2015 :    
  8/7/2015 :  
Thick s
 7/2015 :    
11/11/2014 :    
    1/2015 :    
    7/2015 :  >10%  
 9/2014: Patients
    9/2015 :    
12/2014Act
 10/2014 :    
 11/2014 :    
eumatology :  3-10% 
 12/2014:  
 10/2015 :    
ctober/2014: Patients
ed /2014 :  
9/2013
    8/2014 :  >10% (35%
 10/2014:  
 3/2015: 3-10%  
 3/2015 :    
 9/2015 :  3-10% 
 arthrit  9/2015 
    2/2015 :  3-10% 
 3/2015: >10% 
 5/2015 :    
 /2014 :  3-10% 
 10/2015 :  >10%  
 7/2015 :  3-10% 
 3/2015 :    
: 1  /2015 :    
 5/2015 :  3-10% 
March /2014: 3-10%  
: 3  6/2015: 3-10%  
ar5/2014 :  
 /2015 :    
arthrit :3-10%  
 /2015 :    
10/2014 : 
12/2014Act
    1/2015 :  3-10% 
 3/2015 :  3-10% 
 3/2015 :  3-10% 
d 4/2015 :  Patient
 4/2015 :  >10%  
   11/2015 :  >10%
```

Comment: I don't envy you if you have to do this. It's probably easier to do using c# (or whatever your procedural language of choice is)

Comment: I've started writing a SQL case statement which handles each variant.  When I have that completed I will post it as the answer. In the meantime, I'm hoping someone will show me a more elegant solution.